# Format data to JSON

Tags: java, jackson, gson

I'm facing a problem with converting Map to JSON. Here i'm required to format the data to a nested JSON depending upon payment type,channel and currency. Since the data is not ordered I'm not sure how to achieve this in JAVA.

Input:

```
{by_status=COMPLETED, by_processingDate=2019-08-08, by_paymentType=REALTIME, by_channel=A, by_currency=SGD} count: 79129
{by_status=FAILED, by_processingDate=2019-08-08, by_paymentType=REALTIME, by_channel=B, by_currency=SGD} count: 2
{by_status=FAILED, by_processingDate=2019-08-08, by_paymentType=REALTIME, by_channel=A, by_currency=SGD} count: 79
{by_status=FAILED, by_processingDate=2019-08-10, by_paymentType=REALTIME, by_channel=A, by_currency=SGD} count: 3
{by_status=FAILED, by_processingDate=2019-08-08, by_paymentType=REMITTANCE, by_channel=B, by_currency=SGD} count: 3347
{by_status=FAILED, by_processingDate=2019-08-08, by_paymentType=false, by_channel=A, by_currency=SGD} count: 3
{by_status=PENDING, by_processingDate=2019-08-08, by_paymentType=REALTIME, by_channel=B, by_currency=SGD} count: 2
{by_status=PENDING, by_processingDate=2019-08-08, by_paymentType=REALTIME, by_channel=A, by_currency=SGD} count: 15
{by_status=PENDING, by_processingDate=2019-08-08, by_paymentType=REMITTANCE, by_channel=B, by_currency=SGD} count: 11654
{by_status=PENDING, by_processingDate=2019-08-08, by_paymentType=REMITTANCE, by_channel=B, by_currency=USD} count: 7
```

Expected output:

```
[
    {
      "COUNTRY": "SG",
      "B": {
        "REMITTANCE": [
          {
            "CURRENCY": "SGD",
            "FAILED":3347,
            "PENDING": 11654
          },
          {
            "CURRENCY": "USD",
            "PENDING": 7
          }
        ],
      "REALTIME": [
          {
            "CURRENCY": "SGD",
            "FAILED":2,
            "PENDING": 2
          }
        ]
      },
      "A": {
        "REALTIME": [
          {
            "CURRENCY": "SGD",
            "COMPLETED": 79129,
            "FAILED": 79,
            "PENDING": 15
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include your full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: Hey man, can you please edit your question to include your POJO that represents the data in that file? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write an aggregator. If you need to aggregate multiple messages/events, you might need to keep the input in an in-memory datastructure (or Database depends on the size) and then retrieve it and form the output in whatever format you want.